# Custom Field Type with Multiple Values

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I'd like to create a field type for my plugin called "location" with two text boxes: one that holds a coordinate for latitude, and one for longitude. I haven't figured out yet how to map those two values from HTML input elements in a template to a JSON array in the database.  Is there an elegant way to achieve this with the Craft API?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but I've already built a plugin that has those fields (and more)... https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/smart-map/docs/using-an-address-field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this simply by setting your field type’s [defineContentAttribute()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#defineContentAttribute-detail) method to return `AttributeType::Mixed`, which will tell Craft to JSON-encode its value before storing it in the database.

```php
public function defineContentAttribute()
{
    return AttributeType::Mixed;
}
```

Then, whatever you submit in the field’s post data will be saved as-is.

For example, if your [getInputHtml()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#getInputHtml-detail) method had this:

```php
public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
{
    $lat = (isset($value['lat']) ? $value['lat'] : '');
    $lng = (isset($value['lng']) ? $value['lng'] : '');

    return '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'[lat]" value="'.$lat.'">' .
           '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'[lng]" value="'.$lng.'">';
}
```

Then it would be expected that the resulting post data for your field would look something like:

```php
array(
    'lat' => '12345',
    'lng' => '67890'
)
```

And with `AttributeType::Mixed`, that’s exactly how it would get stored. Behind the scenes it will get JSON-encoded when getting saved to the DB, and JSON-decoded when getting fetched from the DB, but your field type will never need to know about that.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of the `Mixed` attribute type when I posted this. Looks like the JS and the hidden field was extraneous.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (Let's call the fieldtype Geo):

Your field html should output those two fields, and update a hidden input with the correct namespaced fieldname. Get it like this:

```
$id = craft()->templates->formatInputId($name);
$namespaceInputId = craft()->templates->namespaceInputId($id);
```

[See docs here about binding JS to fields.](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types#binding-javascript)

Your fieldtypes content should be defined as Mixed. Craft will encode/decode it to JSON when saving the model automatically.

```
public function defineContentAttribute()
{
    return AttributeType::Mixed;
}
```

In your fieldtypes prepValueFromPost method, you do all the conversion magic for saving. Let's say your JS save the lat/lng values as a pipe separated value in the hidden input field.

```
public function prepValueFromPost($value)
{
    if ( empty($value) )
    {
        return new Geo_GeoModel();
    }

    $coordinates = explode('|', $value);
    $geo = new Geo_GeoModel($coordinates);
    return $geo;
}
```

You also need to hook up the model with the defined attributes:

```
class Geo_GeoModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'lat' => AttributeType::String,
            'lng' => AttributeType::String,
        );
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $render = craft()->templates->render('geo/templates/render', $this);
        return $render;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

I was actually going to make a plugin that does the same. Please share if you do :)

Comment: Hey Fred, you may have already seen this, but I built a plugin which contains those fields (and more)... https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/smart-map/docs/using-an-address-field

Comment: Excellent!  JS and a hidden input were exactly what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if that was the "right" way to do it.